# Updating .NET Standard library to work with ASP.NET Core 2.2 and 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-standard, csproj

I have a .NET Standard library shared between several web apps in our organization. Since all of them use the same scheme for authentication, the code was put into a sharable library. All of the web apps have been targeting `netcoreapp2.2` and the library targets `netstandard2.0`. I have updated the first web app to `netcoreapp3.0` and after doing so it failed on startup with this error:

> System.MissingFieldException: Field not found:
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme'.

Which was thrown from this line in an extension method the library:

`services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);`

This is what the `.csproj` file for the library originally looked prior to the update:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <RootNamespace></RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName></AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="2.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="1.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And this worked for our ASP.NET Core 2.2 apps. After some modifications I got the ASP.NET Core 3.0 app to run after changing the library to this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.0;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <RootNamespace></RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName></AssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp3.0'">
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="1.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="2.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="1.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Is this the preferred/correct way of doing this, or is there something simpler? Should the library be using the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK instead?

Comment: dotnet core 3.0 implements dotnet standard 2.1 (minimum. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard ). Are there any build warnings?

Comment: Can't target netstandard2.1, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` doesn't work with it.

Comment: Actually, it turns out I can keep this project as `netstandard2.0` and continue using it with ASP.NET Core 3.0 if I just change `IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` to `"Windows"`. Error probably related to it changing from `static readonly` in 2.0 to `const` in 3.0?

Answer (score 2):

We had this same issue migrating an authentication library built for .NET standard 2.0, being used in a .NET Core 2.1 application that we migrated to 3.1. We received the same error message about IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme.

Based on your comment (thanks btw!) it looks like yes, they did change that value from a `static readonly string` to a `const string`, a breaking change to be sure, but not a welcome one (at least in the moment). I could not find this specifically mentioned anywhere in the migration documentation (as linked by @McKabue).

Here is the .NET Core 2.2 doc for this field:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.iisintegration.iisdefaults.authenticationscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.2

And here it is for .NET Core 3.0, when the switch was made to a const:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.iisintegration.iisdefaults.authenticationscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.0

## The Fix

As you mentioned in your comment, simply replace `IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` with the string value `"Windows"`, as that is what the field/const value was returning anyways. This sidesteps the compatibility issues between .NET Core 2.2 and .NET 3.0+, without much fuss.

## History

Bing and I looked around for anything specific on this, and found a couple interesting things on Github about it.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3838 - An issue with the value being a field not a const. Note Tratcher says:

> It was a mistake. Yes we should change it but we can't until 3.0. You can use the actual value "Windows" as a workaround.

And then later, the pull request that changed it from a static readonly to a const:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/4342/files/6def4a71dcb45fdd07278c11698bf9595c193dd9

Answer (score 0):

1. If the project, or any of its dependencies is `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` or `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Razor">` then explicitly  add `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`.
2. If the project is `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`, you don't need to add `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`, its added imperatively.
3. If you have azure functions, wait for this fix: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/339

## Read more: ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0

[Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)

[Breaking changes included in EF Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#fromsql)
[What's new in ASP.NET Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-3.0?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

[Breaking changes for migration from Version 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.0)

[ASP.NET Core updates in .NET Core 3.0 Preview 4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-4/)

[Develop Azure Functions using .NET Core 3.0](https://dev.to/azure/develop-azure-functions-using-net-core-3-0-gcm)

[Move ASP.NET Core to Azure Functions in 4 steps](https://reynders.co/move-asp-net-core-to-azure-functions-in-4-steps/)

Also note that when you use multiple `TargetFrameworks`, you have to add multiple implementations:

```
var webRootFileProvider =
#if NETCOREAPP3_0
    GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>().WebRootFileProvider;
#elif NETSTANDARD2_0
    GetRequiredService<IHostingEnvironment>().WebRootFileProvider;
#else
#error unknown target framework
#endif
```